# SUMIF for a wider range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, worksheet-function, sumifs

I have a problem that has been nagging me for a while now. I am a novice in Excel. Hence excuse me if this comes across as silly.

I have the following array of data:
[image: Data]

I need to obtain the sum of values corresponding to the row entry "book". 
I have used the formula sumif(B4:F7,"book",C4:F7). However excel returns the value in column c alone (i.e value returned is 10).

**Update**

I ammended my formula as follows:
[image: Ammended Formula]

I now obtained the correct sum - i.e 70. However, I deal with large volumes of data and using this formula is not efficient. Can anyone suggest a quick workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct. There is a simpler way, but it is not easy to find it out for a novice user. You will need to use an *array formula* to do what you need.

Type this formula:

```
=SUM(IF($B4:$B7="book",$C$4:$F$7,0))
```

and enter it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can see the result in this picture (my delimiter is `;` while yours will be `,`, but that does not make a difference):
[image]

Comment: Was the answer helpful?